# Why cannot bind to port with specified iP address, but it works well with localhost?

Tags: c, network-programming

I am creating a server that send message to all clients if one client send message to server. I tested my server with telnet and two other clients in the in my computer. It works find if I use "localhost" as value in the first argument of function getaddrinfo. BUt when I replace it with my ip address, which I obtain by searching on google, it failed to bind socket to the port. Why that happens?

This works well when I test my telnet.

```
if ((rv = getaddrinfo("localhost", PORT, &hints, &ai)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "selectserver: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    exit(1);
}

for(p = ai; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    listener = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
    if (listener < 0) {
        continue;
    }

    // lose the pesky "address already in use" error message
    setsockopt(listener, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));

    if (bind(listener, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
        close(listener);
        continue;
    }

    break;
}
```

The program fails to bind if I specified the IP addresss
Note: that I replaced my IP addresss with the "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

```
if ((rv = getaddrinfo("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", PORT, &hints, &ai)) != 0) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "selectserver: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: *How* does it fail? Is the ip-address you try to use actually an ip-address of an interface on the system?

Comment: what is the port you're trying to bind? ports lower than 1000, need root access. Also be sure that the port you're trying to bind is not busy with another service. p.s. try 0.0.0.0 instead of your ip adress

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just learned about network programming, so I cannot tell whether it is the actual IP. As I said, I obtained it by searching "my ip" on google. Can you tell me how to get the actual IP address?

Comment: @SunDro my port is 9034. I think it is not busy, because everytime I use "localhost" it works fine. And, 0.0.0.0 works too. But I wonder, whether another computer can connect with the server using ip address 0.0.0.0?

Comment: ip adress 0.0.0.0 means that server will listen all incoming connections via your ip and your localhost too. try to connect from another computer via your ip adress when you're using 0.0.0.0

Comment: The special addredd `0.0.0.0` is the *catch-all* address, and it means bind to all interfaces. How to find the addresses on your system depends on your operating system, but going into network settings would be a good start. Also note that if your system gets its address through DHCP then it might change outside of your control or knowledge.

Comment: I don't have anyother computer to test. Do you know there is any website that allows to test connection to server?

Comment: What OS are you using? If using Linux try `ifconfig | grep inet.addr` to get your IP address.

Comment: Or on Windows try `ipconfig`

Comment: I use Cygwin in window. I just check my ip with ipconfig, and it turns out, it is private address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most unusual to want to bind to `"localhost"` or to your external IP address. Most computers in this day and age don't have an external IP address (the one that Google sees), because there's a router and a demilitarized zone between them and the internet. If you want to expose a service that's visible to your LAN to the internet, then you'll need to configure your router to forward connections, which is a topic that's more suitable for the networking variant of Stack Overflow.

Providing your `hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE`, you should be able to use `NULL` in place of `"localhost"` and `getaddrinfo` will return a list of all suitable interfaces that you can bind on. If your `hints.ai_flags` doesn't contain `AI_PASSIVE`, then there's no guarantee that you can bind on the interfaces returned. Should you choose to use a string here, the `AI_PASSIVE` flag will be ignored anyway...

In your code, you're creating multiple sockets one by one, discarding the previously created as you create the next one... That's a resource leak, and possibly the cause for the problem you've noticed too. Perhaps you intended to store your multiple socket descriptors into an array, and bind them one at a time?

Don't forget to `freeaddrinfo` once you're done with `ai`. In the example below I've used `PF_UNSPEC` together with `SOCK_STREAM` to listen on both IPV4 and IPV6 interfaces (as well as any other stream types), but these can be changed to bind to other types of addresses.

```
#define BIND_ADDR NULL
#define BIND_PORT "1234"

struct addrinfo *ai;
int rv = getaddrinfo(BIND_ADDR,
                     BIND_PORT,
                     &(struct addrinfo){ .ai_family = PF_UNSPEC,
                                         .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM,
                                         .ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE },
                     &ai)
if (rv != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "selectserver: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    exit(1);
}

size_t ai_size = 0;
for (struct addrinfo *a = ai; a != NULL; a = a->ai_next) {
     ai_size++;
}

int socket[ai_size] = { 0 };
size_t x = 0;
for (struct addrinfo *a = ai; a != NULL; a = a->ai_next) {
     socket[x++] = socket(a->ai_family, a->ai_socktype, a->ai_protocol);
     /* ... */
}

freeaddrinfo(ai);
/* ... */
```